# How can I remove grey bar and menu from wordpress

Tags: css, menu, wordpress-theming

Please help. I am using zalive theme and have tried all the css posts i can find in the forum including:

```
#menu-main_menu, {
display: none;
}
```

nothing works as you can see on my site http://www.brendanssportspub.com

its still there (the grey bar that says No categories)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar {
  display: none;
}
```